# Rerender/update a JSF 2.0 custom component using a primefaces command button does not work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component

Thanks in advance for your attention.

I've created a JSF 2.0 custom component to render Google GeoCharts. So, the renderer just writes some javascript and a div at the end.

The component works fine doing that. But my requirement is that the GeoChart should change its values using an ajax request. To do that, i'm using a primefaces command button putting in its attribute "update" the id of the geoChart.

The problem is that the GeoChart is not being updated when the comand button is clicked.

I'm using a maven archetype (myfaces-archetype-jsfcomponents20) allowing the automatic generation of  some configuration files. So, I just need to write to classes and annotations. Those classes are the UIComponent and the Renderer.

I'm running this code in GlassFish 3.1 and Mojarra 2.1.6

The code of those classes:

UIComponent:

```
@JSFComponent(
    name = "processum:geochart",
    clazz = "org.processum.component.gchart.GoogleChart",
    tagClass = "org.processum.component.gchart.GoogleChartTag")

abstract class AbstractGoogleChart extends UIComponentBase {

        public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "org.processum.GoogleChart";
        public static final String DEFAULT_RENDERER_TYPE = "org.processum.GoogleChartRenderer";
        public static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "javax.faces.Output";

    /**
    *
    * GoogleChartModel
    */
    @JSFProperty
    public abstract GoogleGeoChartModel getModel();        
}
```

Renderer:

```
@JSFRenderer(
    renderKitId = "HTML_BASIC",
    family = "javax.faces.Output",
    type = "org.processum.GoogleChartRenderer")
public class GoogleChartRenderer extends Renderer {

@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    GoogleChart chart = (GoogleChart) component;
    String divId = (String) component.getClientId() + "chartDiv";
    GoogleGeoChartModel model = chart.getModel();
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.write("<script type='text/javascript'>"
            + "google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});"
            + "google.setOnLoadCallback(initGeoMap);"
            + "function initGeoMap() {"
            + "var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(["
            + "[");
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    for (String header : model.getHeaders()) {
        data.append("\'").append(header).append("\'").append(",");
    }
    data.deleteCharAt(data.length() - 1).append("],");

    for (String[] value : model.getValues()) {
        data.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                data.append("\'").append(value[i]).append("\'");
            } else {
                data.append(value[i]);
            }
            data.append(",");
        }
        data.deleteCharAt(data.length() - 1).append("],");
    }
    data.deleteCharAt(data.length() - 1);
    writer.write(data.toString());
    writer.write("]);");
    writer.write("var options = {"
            + "region: 'CO',"
            + "displayMode: 'markers'"
            + "};"
            + "var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById(\'" + divId + "\'));"
            + "chart.draw(data, options);"
            + "};"
            + "</script>"
            + "<div id=\"" + divId + "\"/>");
}
}
```

XHTML:

```
<h:form>            
        <div id="anotherContent" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
            <h:panelGroup id="chartCont" layout="block">
                <processum:geochart id="chart" model="#{chartBackBean.model}"/>                   
            </h:panelGroup>
        </div>  
        <p:commandButton id="change" value="Cambio" actionListener="#{chartBackBean.change}" update="chart"/>            
    </h:form>
```

**Some debugging:**

The ajax request is triggered adequately. The managed bean updates the GoogleGeoChartModel with  new values. 
Next, the control flow goes to the Renderer which "encodes" the new values of the chart (that means that the encondeEnd is called again). But, this new "enconding" is not painted in the browser.

The html has two JSF components. My custom component and a h:panelGroup. If in the "update" attribute on primefaces button I put the id of the chart's div and then I trigger the ajax request, the chart does not change. But instead I put the id of the h:panelGroup, the div of the chart disappears.

Comment: Can you check if there are any JavaScript issues on the browser? As well as, can you verify that the content from encodeEnd is being sent in the response?

Comment: Hi @HarshaR. Thank you very much for your attention. About your first question, I guess that is not posible yet to search for js issues because the "new js" that should be renderer does not appear in the browser (I'm using Chrome's inspector). About your second question, I don't know how to verify that the new js is sent in the response.

Comment: Hi @Ephyras, I was talking more from the perspective of - does the web console (Firefox / Chrome) show any JS errors? It looks like the custom component is unable to re-render itself. You might need to unload the geoChart before sending the update, or modify the script being sent.